# Extracting bytes in C

Tags: c, byte, extract

I'm making a program in C. I am to extract bytes. `un8  extractbyte  (int r, int pos)` should return byte number pos from number r. As example, I use as input: `0x7788AABB`. Output then should be:

> Part number 0 is BB
>   Part number 1 is AA
>   Part number 2 is 88
>   Part number 3 is 77

I am stuck at the last part of the program, where I have put the question marks in the comments. Those lines aren't right and I am confused in how I should make it work... The output I get now is bb at every part. I am pretty new at C by the way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned int  un32;
typedef unsigned char  un8;

un8  extractbyte  (un32  r, un8  pos);

int main ()
{
    un32  number;
    un8     k;

    printf("Enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%x",&number); 

    for (k=0; k<=3;k++)
        printf ("Part number %d is:  %x \n", k , extractbyte(number, k) );

    return 0;
}

un8 extractbyte  (un32  r ,  un8  pos)
{
    un32  mask;
    un32 size = pos*8;
    un32; // ??
    un8; // ??

    return (un8)  r; // ??
}
```

Comment: I think I will have to use >> and/or & in the last couple of lines. But I am not sure how to do this... I keep getting errors when I use these though so I'm pretty much lost.

Comment: Paper and pen. To extract the n-th group of bytes, you will have to shift the number to the right by `8 * n` places, then mask out all but the remaining (now least significant) byte by `AND`ing it with `0xff`.

Comment: You should give it a go, and then ask where you've gone wrong if it doesn't work, rather than just asking someone to write it for you. Also, fwiw, `unsigned int` and `unsigned char` are not necessarily 32 and 8 bits long, respectively. Consider using `sizeof()` and `CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: Even better, use the `typedef`s that the standard foresees when you what to have types of a fixed width, namely `uint8_t` and `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 4):

```
un8 extractbyte(un32 r, un8 pos)
{
    return (r >> (8 * pos)) & 0xFF;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would make your `extractbyte` function something like this.

```
int extractbyte(int n, int pos)
{
    return (n >> (pos * 8)) & 0xff;
}
```

Comment: @H2CO3: yes, they could be omitted; they should not be omitted.

Comment: @Jonathan yup, I accept that :) Sometimes I omit parentheses... just for readability.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Why not? `*` has higher precedence than `>>`.

Comment: For readability and clarity.  It prevents any possibility of confusion by either humans or computers.  Computers don't need the parentheses; humans benefit from them, I think, in this case.  All else apart, when mixing arithmetic and bitwise operations, it is best to keep them clearly separated.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I agree that C didn't get all precedences right... :/

Comment: I shifted around some stuff but nothing seems to work really... I am having quite a hard time with understanding bits and bytes in C.

Comment: @Mobi: Rather than "shifting around some stuff", did you try the code I posted?

Comment: Yeah I did, but I get an error saying conflicting types for ‘extractbyte’ int extractbyte(int n, int pos) ^. Sorry, my mind is all gone now..

Comment: @Mobi: You need to change your function declaration at the top. I changed all the arguments and return value to `int` because I hate custom types like you had. But it should basically work the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char extractbyte(int number, int v) {
    char *x=(char *)&number;
    return x[3-v];
}

int main() {

    int n=0x7788aabb;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        printf("%d) %x\n",i,(unsigned char)extractbyte(n,i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char *x=(char *)&number; return x[3-v]` appears to depend on `number` having a certain endian, maybe big endian.